# Checkbox Button Group - Checked Option

Tags: visualforce-component, checkbox

I am facing problems trying to make a reusable component on React of the CheckBox-Button-Group (https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/checkbox-button-group/).

The component is rendering fine but the problem is that changing its checked prop, selected background doesn't change. What's the prop i should change to make the background selected appear (as on the documentation).

I copy whats being rendered on my app (as you see its quite same as on documentation).

```
                    <Form.CheckboxButtonGroup
                        ref="platforms"
                        name="platforms"
                        placeholder="platforms"
                        readOnly={this.props.readOnly}
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                        defaultValue={platforms}
                    >
                        {Object.keys(platforms).map(key =>
                            <Form.CheckBoxButton
                            ref={key}
                            key={key}
                            placeholder={key}
                            readOnly={this.props.readOnly}
                            defaultChecked={platforms[key]}
                            />)}
                    </Form.CheckboxButtonGroup>


   <div class="slds-form-element__control">
    <div class="slds-checkbox_button-group">
      <span class="slds-button slds-checkbox_button">
        <input type="checkbox" placeholder="ios" name="checkbox" 
         value="on">
        <label class="slds-checkbox_button__label">
          <span class="slds-checkbox_faux">ios</span>
        </label>
      </span>
      <span class="slds-button slds-checkbox_button">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" placeholder="android" 
         value="on">
        <label class="slds-checkbox_button__label">
          <span class="slds-checkbox_faux">android</span>
        </label>
      </span>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The checkox group in the Lightning Design System uses a basic HTML behaviour.

In fact, when a label is associated to an input using the input `Id` and the `for` property of the label, you can click on the label to enter the input.

In the Lightning Design System, the checkboxes are displayed behind the labels. So, when you click on the label, the HTML behaviour make the checkbox state change thanks to the link between the input `Id` and the label `for` attribute.

So each of the checkboxes inside the checkbox group must have an `Id` defined. And the label associated must be linked to this `Id` using its `for` attribute. Like this:

```
<div class="slds-form-element__control">
    <div class="slds-checkbox_button-group">
      <span class="slds-button slds-checkbox_button">
        <input id="checkbox-1" type="checkbox" placeholder="ios" name="checkbox" 
         value="on">
        <label for="checkbox-1" class="slds-checkbox_button__label">
          <span class="slds-checkbox_faux">ios</span>
        </label>
      </span>
      <span class="slds-button slds-checkbox_button">
        <input id="checkbox-2" type="checkbox" name="checkbox" placeholder="android" 
         value="on">
        <label for="checkbox-2" class="slds-checkbox_button__label">
          <span class="slds-checkbox_faux">android</span>
        </label>
      </span>
   </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have added that missing props but nothing seems to happen. This thing is annoying me :/ What else could be?

Comment: Solved it. I was missing a "_" on slds-checkbox_button__label class. I deserve dead ha ha